# How to check a variable is empty or not in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I tried many possible ways but nothing is working.

```
public function addArea($data=''){
    var_dump($data); //returning -> string(0) ""
    if(empty($data)){  //if 1
        $header['title'] = "Add Area";
        $data['title'] = "Add Area";
    }
    if(!empty($data)){  //if2
        $header['title'] = "Update Area";
        $data['title'] = "Update Area";
    }

    echo $header['title']; die; // returning Update Area
    }
```

The problem is when I am calling the function both "if" are getting true and then I am getting Value "Update Area".
But I want when I call the function without a parameter 1st if should work and if I call the function with parameter then only second if should work.

I have tried

```
if($data=='') | if($data!='')
```

also

Comment: Add in the parameter ($data=NULL) and check for it. You are now returning an empty string.

Comment: already tried that, no deference, same result

Comment: How do you check this in your function?

Comment: tried two ways, 1 -> same as above.
2-> if(is_null($data)){}

Comment: That is tot correct: if($data == null)

Comment: this also produces the same result as my problem, no fix.
why don't you try it before answering, because this is becoming a chat conversation?

Comment: You need also to use an if(){.....}else{.......} statement for that. You have now two if statements

Comment: I know that is the last easy solution (using else) but I need to know why that code is behaving that way?

Comment: Suggest u to use if else. Instead to 2 IF. `if(empty($data)){}else{}`

Comment: empty will not work. In your case $data must be null and check it as `if(!isset($data)){..data is not set...}else{..data is set...}. In my previous comment I have already told you to NOT USE 2 if statement. You are also probably using `php version lower the 5.5

Comment: You are expecting $data to be an array with a key of 'title'. So in this particular instance, you need to check if it's an array and if $data['title'] is set. So use if(is_array($data) and isset($data['title'])) { Do the update} else {No Update} And then you might want to check if it's empty...

Answer (score 2):

First way

```
if (empty($var)) {
    echo 'First way to check empty or not';
}
```

Second way

```
if (isset($var)) {
    echo 'First way to check empty or not';
}
```

For you second option is better

Answer (score 0):

well, I was trying to get more detail on this but it seems nobody has more details, they all referring to the same answer which I already knew.

Answer is: **Just use else instead of 2nd if**

```
public function addArea($data=''){
var_dump($data); //returning -> string(0) ""
if(empty($data)){  //if 1
    $header['title'] = "Add Area";
    $data['title'] = "Add Area";
}
else{  //just use else instead of 2nd if
    $header['title'] = "Update Area";
    $data['title'] = "Update Area";
}

echo $header['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (isset($data))  //true if $data have value
```